# A question of theodicy

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, commentaries, theodicy

A lot of people are bothered by the fact that bad things happen to good people and good things happen to bad people.  Chazal answers by saying that it all averages out in the World to Come.

But I don't see why that is a problem in the first place. The Torah says:
“Good things will happen to you if you observe the commandments”, 
but does not say:
“Nothing bad will ever happen to you if you observe the commandments”.

Likewise, The Torah says:
“Bad things will happen to you if you don’t observe the commandments”, 
but does not say:
“Nothing good will ever happen to you if you don't observe the commandments”.

Has this point ever been noted by the commentators?

Comment: You make 5 unsourced claims about what Chazal and/or the Torah say.

Comment: You are interpreting it wrongly, Judaism does not work with the formal logics, forget it. If I say " I'll give you $5" that means I will not take from you anything. Same here, when G-d says He will do good, it implies - no bad things will happen and vice verse. BTW this is absolutely true about the vast majority of Sugyot of the Gemmorah.

Comment: "Judaism does not work with the formal logic".  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talmudical_hermeneutics

Comment: Source please: **Chazal answers by saying that it all averages out in the World to Come**

Comment: @DannySchoemann -- Kiddushin 39b is one source.  Peah 1:1.  Many others.